# Extracting unique words

Tags: ruby

I need to take a file name and an integer N, and return the first N unique words in the file given. Let us say that `input.txt` has this content:

```
I like pancakes in my breakfast. Also, I like pancakes in my dinner.
```

The output of running this with N = 13 could be

```
I
like
pancakes
in
my
breakfast.
Also,
dinner.
```

I know how to open the file and read line by line, but beyond that, I don't know how to take the unique words out if the lines.

Comment: Someone may reply with a complete program, but we really shouldn't do that to people who are learning. Look up `Array#split` and `Array#uniq` to get started.

Comment: Hint: Use a `lazy` enumerator if you're concerned about over-processing, and take `take(13)`.

Comment: _"I know how to open the file and read line by line"_ Okay, what do you end up with?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You could use a [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

Comment: @Phlip `Array#split` does not exist.

Comment: Good point. But I'm sure Professor Google will make something of "ruby array split"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first create a test file.

```
str =<<END
We like pancakes for breakfast,
but we know others like waffles.
END

FName = 'temp'
File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 65 (characters written)
```

We need to return an array containing the first `nbr_unique` unique words from the file named `file`, so let's write a method that will do that.

```
def unique_words(fname, nbr_unique)
  <code needed here>
end
```

You need to add unique words to an array that will be returned by this method, so let's begin by creating an empty array and then return that array at the end of the method.

```
def unique_words(fname, nbr_unique)
  arr = []
  <code needed here>
  arr
end
```

You know how to read a file line-by-line, so let's do that, using the class method [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach>)<sup>1</sup>.

```
def unique_words(fname, nbr_unique)
  arr = []
  File.foreach(fname) do |line|
    <code need here to process line>
  end
  arr
end
```

The block variable `line` equals `"We like pancakes for breakfast,\n"` after the first line is read. Firstly, the newline character needs to be removed. Examine the methods of the class 
[String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) to see if one can be used to do that.

The second line contains the word `"we"`. I assume `"We"` and `"we"` are not to be regarded as unique words. This is usually handled by converting all characters of a string to either all lowercase or all uppercase. You can do this to each line or to each word (after words have been extracted from a line).  Again, look for a suitable method in the class `String` for doing this.

Next you need to extract words from each line. Once again, look for a `String` method for doing that.

Next we need to determine if, say, `"like"` (or `"LIKE"`) is to be added to the array `arr`. Look at the instance methods for the class [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html) for a suitable method. If it is added we need to see if `arr` now contains `nbr_unique` words. If it does we don't need to read any more lines of the file, so we need to break out of `foreach`'s block (perhaps use the keyword `break`).

There's one more thing we need to take care of. The first line contains  `"breakfast,"`, the second, `"waffles."`. We obviously don't want the words returned to contain punctuation. There are two ways to do that. The first is to remove the punctuation, the second is to accept only letters.

Given a string that contains punctuation (a line or a word) we can create a second string that equals the original string with the punctuation removed. One way to do that is to use the method [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr). Suppose the string is `"breakfast,"`. Then

```
"breakfast,".tr(".,?!;:'", "") #=> "breakfast"
```

To only accept letters we could use any of the following regular expressions (all return `"breakfast"`):

```
"breakfast,".gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+/, "")
"breakfast,".gsub(/[a-z]+/i, "")
"breakfast,".gsub(/[[:alphaa:]]+/, "")
"breakfast,".gsub(/\p{L}+/, "")
```

The first two work with ASCII characters only. The third (POSIX) and fourth work (*\p{} construct*) with Unicode (search within [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html)).

Note that it is more efficient to remove punctuation from a line before words are extracted.

**Extra credit: use [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object)**

Whenever you see an object (here `arr`) initialized to be be empty, manipulated and then returned at the end of a method, you should consider using the method `Enumerator#with_object` or (more commonly), [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). Both of these return the object referred to in the method name.

The method `IO::foreach` returns an enumerator (an instance of the class `Enumerator`) when it does not have a block (see doc). We therefore could write

```
def unique_words(fname, nbr_unique)
  File.foreach(fname).with_object([]) do |line, arr|
    <code need here to process line>
  end
end
```

We have eliminated two lines (`arr = []` and `arr`), but have also confined `arr`'s scope to the block. This is not a big deal but is the Ruby way.

**More extra credit: use methods of the class [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)**

Suppose we wrote the following.

```
require 'set'

def unique_words(fname, nbr_unique)
  File.foreach(fname).with_object(Set.new) do |line, set|
    <code need here to process line>
  end.to_a
end
```

When we extract the word `"we"` from the second line we need to check if it should be added to the set. Since sets have unique elements we can just try to do it. We won't be able to do that because `set` will already contain that word from the first line of the file. A handy method for doing that is [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F):

```
set.add?("we")
  #=> nil
```

Here the method returns `nil`, meaning the set already contains that word. It also tells us that we don't need to check if the set now contains `nbr_unique` words. Had we been able to add the word to the set, `set` (with the added word) would be returned.

The block returns the value of `set` (a set). The method [Set#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-to_a) converts that set to an array, which is returned by the method.

<sup>1 Notice that I've invoked the class method `IO::foreach` by writing `File.foreach(fname)...` below. This is permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File.superclass #=> IO`). I could have instead written `IO.foreach(fname)...`, but it is more common to use `File` as the receiver.</sup>